# Read binary file position by position and convert it?

Tags: c#, readfile, binaryreader

I Know on VB we can read binary file using this code

```
    Function GetMonData()
            Dim Header(63) As Byte, Rows As Long, NoUse As Long
            Dim i As Long, j As Long, TmpStr As String

            Open "file.dat" For Binary As #1
                Get #1, , Header
                Get #1, , Rows
                Get #1, , NoUse       
            Close #1
    End Function
```

But how about method in c# ?
especially `Get #1, , Header` 
I already try

```
string strFilePath = @"C:\file.dat";
FileStream stream = new FileStream(strFilePath, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open(strFilePath, FileMode.Open));
```

I just confused to get data (63) byte for header , (4) byte for Rows, (4) byte for NoUse
in VB we can use `Get #1, , Header`, What about c# ? i need to Seek for the stream ?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is VB6/VBA code.  The olden syntax is still supported in VB.NET, grudgingly, to permit porting programs.  But surely you'll have to change the declarations from Long to Integer.

If you need to be able to read old files like this then the most obvious way to do it is to take advantage of .NET's excellent language interop and create a VB.NET class library that you reference in your C# project.  By far the best way to ensure that the code is compatible and can deal with the weirdo semantics of Get().

Otherwise you'll have to use BinaryReader.GetBytes() to read Header, ReadInt32() to get the other ones.

Comment: hei thanks for your answer , i used BinaryReader.GetBytes() , and the other ones ReadInt32() like your answer , but the console just show me the header , the other ones never show me the value , so i need to use for loop to print that ReadInt32() ? because the console like stuck after Header, Thanks

Comment: Nvm , problem solved :)
The Solution is Convert.ToInt32(ReadInt32()) . so the value now become visible
Thank you very much Hans !